# Desktop wallpaper won't display images, only colours and gradients

Tags: gnome, 10.10, desktop-background

On my ubuntu 10.10 laptop, I've recently noticed (I'm a busy guy and don't focus on my minimalist wallpaper) that my wallpaper has disappeared and been replaced with a coloured background - annoyingly similar to the image I had before, which means I have no idea when it changed.

I've tried different image types, sizes, and filesizes, but I can't get any images to load - not even the defaults. I also have no idea how to debug this. Any help would be much obliged!

Comment: In order for us to give you a little help could you let us know some or all of the following info:                     1 Have you recently upgraded from an older version of Ubuntu?                                                     2 What appears when you hit alt and f2 and type Appearance?                                                 3 Do you use Unity or have the other gnome classic background? 4 If the latter what happens when you select system>preferences>appearance?   5 Last question. What files do you have in /usr/share/backgrounds folder in your file system?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using compiz with the compiz-wallpaper option activated? If so, the default wallpaper dialog in appearance-properties has no effect since would be overrided by compiz. Check it in ccsm and if is enabled, disable it.